# I am trying to write numbers 1 - 4096 in a .TXT file using a For Loop, but when the loop is finished, there is only the number 4096 in the .TXT file

Tags: python, string, for-loop, integer

I have 2 files:

`text.txt`

And:

`main.py`

In `main.py`, I have the following code:

```
for i in range(1,4097):
    i = str(i)
    file = open("text.txt","w")
    file.write(i)
```

As you can see, I want to generate all numbers from 1 - 4096, but when I run the script, it only writes `4096` in `text.txt`.

How can I write numbers 1 - 4096 inside `text.txt`?

(By the way, I made `i` a string (`str()`) because I cannot write an `int()` (`i`) in a text file.

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed this is by doing this:

```py
file = open("text.txt","a")
for i in range(1,4097):
    i = str(i)
    file.write(str(i) + "\n")

file.close()
```

Instead of this:

```py
for i in range(1,4097):
    i = str(i)
    file = open("text.txt","w")
    file.write(i)
```

As you can see, the reason it did not work is when `open("text.txt","w")` ran, it overrighted `text.txt` everytime because `open("text.txt")` was set to `write` mode (`w`) not `append` mode (`a`). So everytime it ran, it overrighted each number. Also, if I wanted to make a newline every time it ran, all I would need to do is replace `file.write(str(i))`, with this: `file.write(str(i) + "\n")`.

Answer (score 5):

You should place the open call before entering the for-loop. Otherwise you will overwrite the file every time.

Comment: Thank you SOOO much. This worked. But do you know how to write each new number on a newline? Because now it is just writing "123456789.....4096" And I would like it to write like ```1\n2\n3\n4.....4095\n4096```

Comment: I am not sure if it works but you could try to add "\n" to each string.

Comment: @Daniel try adding newline character when writing: `file.write(i + '\n')`

Comment: Just use `print(i, file=file)` really. It adds the newline and you can omit the `i = str(i)`

Answer (score 1):

You want to have the file descriptor opened during the entire loop:

```
with open('text.txt', 'w') as op:
   for i in range(0,10):
       op.write(f'{i}\n')
```

Also using f strings you avoid the cast of i to string.

Comment: @fsimonjetz that's interesting! something like op.write(print(i)) would do the trick?

Comment: Replace the line `op.write(f'{i}\n')` with `print(i, file=op)`. It both adds a newline and does the string casting.

Comment: By the way, +1 for the `with...as`, that's the way it's done! :)

Answer (score -1):

This is caused by the ‘w+’ in `file=open(‘test.txt’,‘w+’)`.
It should work if you replace the ‘w+’ with ‘a+’.
This is because `w+` overrides the file, so the numbers are written, but are replaced by the next number straight away, leading to only the last number remaining.
`a+` appends to the file, so you will get all the numbers from 1 to 4096 in test.txt.
As a side note, you forgot to close the file, which could lead to problems later.
This is how you should preferably write the code:

```
for i in range(1,4097):
    with open("text.txt", "a+") as file:
        file.write(f"\n{i}")
```

This is better because it automatically closes the file after anything in the with block is run. You could also write `file.close()` at the end instead of doing this, but that takes one more line of code.
`f'\n{i}` makes sure there's a new line before the next number is printed.

Comment: right, I got it. Fixed the quotes.